# Setting different steps for Y-Axes of ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to set the scaling interval of my Y-Axes different than Mathematica automatically does. So in steps of 1000 instead of 2000 (see picture)

At the moment I determined following PlotRange:

```
PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 8000}}
```

[image]

Is there a simple option?

To get an overview over the command:

```
ListPlot [
  MapThread[
   If[Or[#1[[1]] === 3., #1[[1]] === 8.], 
     Callout[Tooltip[#1, #2], #2], Tooltip[#1, #2]] &, Annotated2], 
  FrameLabel -> {"Happiness Score", 
    "Education Expenditure (per capita)"}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 8000}}] // Framed
```

Comment: You may be looking for the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) option to plotting functions. Try adding something like `Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 8000, 1000]}` to your plot; if you are using a frame in your plot, you may have to use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`. If you show the code that generated the plot, we could help more specifically.

Comment: Hey, Ticks didnt work unfortunately. I added the command above. I just want to adjust the steps of the Y-Axes into steps of 1000 instead of 2000

Comment: I think I swapped the order of arguments in `Ticks`; since you are using a frame in the plot (i.e. `Frame -> True`) , try adding `FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 8000, 1000], Automatic}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify both `Ticks`/`FrameTicks` and `GridLines`

```
xtick = Range[0, 8, 1];
ytick = Range[0, 8000, 1000];
xgrid = Range[0, 8, 2];
ygrid = Range[0, 8000, 2000];
ListPlot[Transpose[{RandomReal[{0, 8}, 20], RandomReal[{0, 8000}, 20]}], 
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> {xgrid, ygrid},
  FrameTicks -> {{ytick, None}, {xtick, None}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8000}}]
```

[image]